# Post categories to pages

Tags: posts, categories, pages

I'm very ( VERY! ) new to WordPress and I'm having some issues with the following:

I created multiple pages like so: [image: wordpress pages]

and I created categories too:
[image: wordpress categories]

Now how do I assign each post in a category to appear in it's page? ( A post with category 'Dicas' should appear on page 'Dicas' )

I'm running version 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Generally, pages cannot be added to categories or tags by default. Posts can can be categorized and tags.

If you google search "WordPress categorize pages" at least a couple of plugins can probably help you figure it out.

Otherwise, you can check [out the code](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/post-tags-and-categories-for-pages/trunk/post-tag.php) for some of those plugins to see how it's done and do it yourself, fairly simply. The main thing to note is that you're *adding* pages to the list of post types that categories and tags can be associated with:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
```